# What commands the suspend item in system menu really launch?

Tags: 14.04, unity, command-line, suspend, power-management

On my laptop trying to go in sleep mode using the Unity `Sleep` item (or closing the lid for what it is worth) does not work well (it goes in suspend mode very slowly and after that I am unable to wake the laptop correctly).

When I use a simple `sudo pm-suspend` everything is working fine and quick.

I thus would like to know exactly what actions are done by Unity when trying to go in sleep mode.

Just for the sake of information I currently use Ubuntu 14.04 on a MacBookPro10,1 (first *retina* edition) using the integrated graphics card (discrete one, which is an nvidia, is powered off so that suspend and brightness control may be usable) and after booting directly using EFI (using rEFInd and linux kernel efistub).

Answer (score 2):

`systemd-logind` manages user sessions in 14.04 (replacing consolekit and upower with login1), the command to used by the system menu to suspend the system is:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true
```